# (lib)mpg123 use of function mpg123_index in C#

Tags: c#, c, pointers, mono

I'm using mpg123 inside my project to decode mp3. I spoke with the developer (Thomas Orgis) about a performance issue when seeking and he had a great idea: Scan the file and afterwards set the scanned index to the playback handle.
So I want to use mpg123_index and mpg123_set_index inside my C# project and use a wrapper around libmpg123.

The wrapper is not self written, I also contacted the developer, but he seems to be unavailable. So maybe someone has knowledge of pointer programming, I also did some things myself, but currently I only get a AccessViolationException when calling the method.

Here some Code:
Wrapper specification (maybe this is wrong?!):

```
[DllImport(Mpg123Dll)]public static extern int mpg123_index(IntPtr mh, IntPtr offsets, IntPtr step, IntPtr fill);
```

Specification on Website (C):

https://www.mpg123.de/api/group__mpg123__seek.shtml#gae1d174ac632ec72df7dead94c04865fb

> MPG123_EXPORT int mpg123_index    (   mpg123_handle *     mh,         off_t ** 
>     offsets,        off_t *     step,       size_t *    fill    )
>
> Give access to the frame index table that is managed for seeking. You
>   are asked not to modify the values... Use mpg123_set_index to set the
>   seek index
>
> Parameters
>       mh    handle
>       offsets   pointer to the index array
>       step  one index byte offset advances this many MPEG frames
>       fill  number of recorded index offsets; size of the array
>
> Returns
>       MPG123_OK on success

My try to use the function in C#:

```
IntPtr pIndex = IntPtr.Zero;
IntPtr pFill = IntPtr.Zero;
IntPtr pStep = IntPtr.Zero;
if (MPGImport.mpg123_index(this.mp3Handle,pIndex,pStep,pFill) != (int)MPGImport.mpg123_errors.MPG123_OK)) 
{
    log.error("Failed!");
}
```

So, has anyone an idea, how to use the function properly on C# side? From the author of mpg123 I just got the information, that the pIndex will be a pointer to the internal index. So this pointer will be changed by this function.

Thanks for your help.

Sincerely
Sven

Edit:
Now the following code almost works:

```
[DllImport(Mpg123Dll)]public unsafe static extern int mpg123_index(IntPtr mh, long **offsets, long *step, ulong *fill);
[DllImport(Mpg123Dll)]public unsafe static extern int mpg123_set_index(IntPtr mh, long* offsets, long step, ulong fill);

public static Boolean CopyIndex(IntPtr _sourceHandle,IntPtr _destinationHandle)
{
    Boolean copiedIndex = false;
    unsafe
    {
        long* offsets = null; 
        long step = 0;
        ulong fill = 0;
        int result = MPGImport.mpg123_index(_sourceHandle, &offsets, &step, &fill);
        if (result == (int)MPGImport.mpg123_errors.MPG123_OK)
        {
            result = MPGImport.mpg123_set_index(_destinationHandle, offsets, step, fill);
            if (result == (int)mpg123_errors.MPG123_OK)
            {
                copiedIndex = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return copiedIndex;
}
```

On `result = MPGImport.mpg123_set_index(_destinationHandle, offsets, step, fill);` the result is -1, which is `MPG123_ERR = -1,     /**< Generic Error */`.

Comment: `public static extern int mpg123_index(IntPtr mh, IntPtr offsets, IntPtr step, IntPtr fill);` is not ok, there is zero pointer to int in the argument of the function `MPG123_EXPORT int mpg123_index ( mpg123_handle * mh, off_t ** offsets, off_t * step, size_t * fill )`, that clearly wrong

Comment: Thanks for your comment :). I already assumed an error in the signature. Do you know, what it should look like?

Comment: I don't really know, but I would make a try with `public static extern int mpg123_index(IntPtr mh, long **offsets, long *step, ulong *fill);` call like that `long *offsets = null; long step = ???; ulong fill= ???; iMPGImport.mpg123_index(this.mp3Handle, &offsets, &step, &fill);`

Comment: Thanks, this almost seems to work, I got a pointer back. I edited the question. The only problem now is, to store the index back to the destination handle. Do you have an idea, why this could fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working code:

```
[DllImport(Mpg123Dll)]public unsafe static extern int mpg123_index(IntPtr mh, long **offsets, long *step, ulong *fill);
[DllImport(Mpg123Dll)]public unsafe static extern int mpg123_set_index(IntPtr mh, long* offsets, long step, ulong fill);

public static Boolean CopyIndex(IntPtr _sourceHandle,IntPtr _destinationHandle)
{
    Boolean copiedIndex = false;
    unsafe
    {
        long* offsets = null; 
        long step = 0;
        ulong fill = 0;
        int result = MPGImport.mpg123_index(_sourceHandle, &offsets, &step, &fill);
        if (result == (int)MPGImport.mpg123_errors.MPG123_OK)
        {
            result = MPGImport.mpg123_set_index(_destinationHandle, offsets, step, fill);
            if (result == (int)mpg123_errors.MPG123_OK)
            {
                copiedIndex = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return copiedIndex;
}
```

_sourceHandle and _destinationHandle may not be IntPtr.Zero, that was my mistake. Thanks for Stargateur, really nice help!